# JQ issues with comments on Json file

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I'm using JQ https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ to work in bash with my json and when I read the json is throwing me an error

```
   parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 5=
```

Since my json has some comments

```
  // comment
  "spawn": {}
```

I've been seen looking the options and I cannot find any option to fix the problem. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is that comment line `line 2`? Is the `"spawn"` line `line 2`? Are comments even legal in json at all?

Comment: Nope the Json is just an example

Comment: You do realize you can't show us a literal error message and then give us different input, right? We can't possibly help with that in general? (Other than in this case from your telling us that you have invalid json input to begin with).

Comment: if you only have comments on separate lines then you can quickly grep them out `cat myjson.jsonc | grep -v "^\s*//" `  . But keep in mind that this won't remove comments which are appended to the line `"prop": 123  // this comment wont be removed` .  You can run `grep -n "^\s*//" ` to check what is about to be excluded.

Comment: I've created a cli tool which uses Microsoft's jsonc-parser to parse and modify json with comments: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-cli

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JSON and thus jq do not support comments (in the usual sense) in JSON input. The jq FAQ lists a number of tools that can be used to remove comments, including jsonlint, json5, and any-json. I'd recommend one that can act as a filter.

See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json for links and further details.

——

It might be worth pointing out that jq can be used to process JSON with `#`-style comments, at least if the JSON is not too large to be processed as a jq program. For example, you could use jq with the -f option to read a JSON file as a jq program.

Answer (score 5):

I found https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-json-comments-cli which allows you to do:

```
cat my_json_with_comments.json | strip-json-comments | jq  .
```

Comment: If you dont want to install the npm package `cat tsconfig.json | npx strip-json-comments-cli | jq | sponge tsconfig.json`

Comment: This is equivalent, `npx` still installs the npm package.

Answer (score 5):

Can be stripped out using sed, eg to remove lines beginning with '//':

```
cat test.json | sed 's/^ *\/\/.*//' | jq <>commands>
```

sed is a pass-through/stream editor, in this case it's substituting nothing ( // ) for lines that begin with '//'; '//' must be escaped with a backslash character since the '/' is used by sed as a delimiter.

Comment: comments can be not only from beginning of line, something like this

`{
  "name":"value" //don't know why this value is here
}`

Comment: The good thing about this solution is its simplicity and portability. As long as one knows that comments are always in their own lines, then this approach is fine.
It's better to use `\s` instead of ` ` in the regex pattern to detect all white space characters (e.g. tab). And as the regex pattern includes `/`, I would change the sed delimiter to `|` resulting in this command: `sed 's|^\s*//.*||'`

Comment: It's also good practice to avoid pipes where possible, so `sed 's|^\s*//.*||' test.json` should be preferred over `cat test.json | sed 's|^\s*//.*||'`

Answer (score 4):

Remove them; JSON does not support comments.

(JSON is defined [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf); you can see a briefer description of the grammar [here](http://json.org).)

Comment: @paul Then you can't use a tool that parses json directly.

Comment: You can remove them from the stream that `jq` reads, however: `sed '|//.*||' my.json | jq ...`.

Comment: For the record, the suggestion to use `sed 's|//.*||'` has a good chance of working in practice but then again, it may not. If it is known that all the // comments start in column 1, then you could safely use `sed 's|^//.*||'`; otherwise, it would be safer to use one of the tools mentioned elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 1):

For C/C++ style comments you can use the C preprocessor to strip comment (`-E`) and not insert line markers (`-P`) like so:

```
 cpp -P -E <FILENAME> | jq .
```

Note: JSON doesn't support comments, JSONC does.

Answer (score -2):

With this sed, you can remove:

1. Empty lines
2. Comments, even in the format `"key": "value" //my comment`

Eventually, json will be output, which can be processed without problems using jq

`sed '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/\/\/.*//' my.json | jq '.<your_block>'`

reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157619

Comment: Works great until you have an http:// or https:// or other URL in your JSON file.

Comment: This is equivalent to [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/735926). It "works" until it doesn’t.