# Jq parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, jq

I am trying to get values from a json file from a url using curl and then printing specific keys with jq command (e.g. company). Unfortunately when I use:
`jq '.[] | .company' JB.json`
I get the error: 
`parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 9`. I have checked the downloaded file with less and it looks exactly like in the url.

Some people suggested to use the -R option but it prints:
`jq: error: Cannot iterate over string`

The url of the file is: https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york

Answer (score 2):

If you use `curl -sS` to retrieve the file, the '//'-style comments are skipped:

```
curl -Ss 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york' | jq '.[] | .company' 
"BentoBox"
"Aon Cyber Solutions"
"Sesame"
"New York University"
```

So presumably your JB.json contains the "//"-style comments.  The simplest workaround would probably be to filter out those first two lines (e.g. using `sed` (or jq!)) first.

Here's a jq-only solution:

```
< JB.json jq -Rr 'select( test("^//")|not)' |
   jq '.[] | .company'
```

Comment: More ways to remove comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358551/978917