# What JSON formatter does Visual Studio Code use to format JSON?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, formatting, format, jq

Visual Studio Code has built-in JSON tools, including a formatter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_formatting

1. What underlying JSON formatter does Visual Studio Code use?
2. Is it available to use as a command line tool outside of Visual Studio Code?
3. How does it differ from [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to find the info you're looking for

- Find the source code for the extension you're interested in. In this case, it's a builtin VS Code extension, so see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions. There, you'll see the json-language-features subdirectory.
- Open https://github.dev/microsoft/vscode
- Open the Search view and expand the Search Details

  - In "File to include", put "extensions/json-language-features/**/*.ts".
  - Enable regex mode and in the search field, put `\bformat\b`.
- Learn that in [jsonServer.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/json-language-features/server/src/jsonServer.ts), there's an `onFormat` function that makes a call to `languageService.format`, where languageService comes from `getLanguageService`, which comes from the [`vscode-json-languageservice`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice) package.
- Look at [microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/jsonLanguageService.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/blob/main/src/jsonLanguageService.ts) and learn that `getLanguageService` returns an object containing `format: (document: TextDocument, range: Range, options: FormattingOptions) => format(document, options, range),`, where `format` comes from `import { format } from './utils/format';`.
- Look at [microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/utils/format.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/blob/main/src/utils/format.ts) and learn that `format` calls `formatJSON`, where that comes from `import { format as formatJSON, Range as JSONCRange } from 'jsonc-parser';`.
- Look at [microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/blob/main/package.json)'s `"dependencies"` field, and see that it depends on [the `jsonc-parser` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser).

So to answer your questions:

> 1. What underlying JSON formatter does Visual Studio Code use?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser

> 2. Is it available to use as a command line tool outside of Visual Studio Code?

Yes. Use it in the same way that microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice uses it. Add it as a dependency of a JS project in the same way you'd depend on any other NPM package.

> 3. How does it differ from jq? https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Well, for one thing, it supports JSON with comments, which jq doesn't (see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json and [JQ issues with comments on Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33352930/11107541)).